# JTabbedPane Not working with Button and ComboBox as expected

Tags: java, swing

I am having a problem with Java's Swing library.  I added an `Admission Class` to `JTabbedPane`.  The `Button` and `ComboBox` components on the first tab appear not to be working but, but when I remove `setLayout(null)` it seems to work, but this leads to other problems with the layout...

Below is what I have tried thus far:

**DBProjectPractice.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Container; 
import java.awt.Font; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.GridLayout; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane; 
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; 
public class DBProjectPractice extends JFrame { 
   private Container contentPane; 
   private String User = null; 
   public String getUser() { 
      String user = this.User; 
      return user; 
   } 
   public DBProjectPractice() { 
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
      init(); 
   } 
   JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane(); 
   JTabbedPane createTabbedPane() {    // tab pane init 
      pane.addTab("text", new Admission());      // 입사 탭의 레이아웃.  
      pane.addTab("text", new JLabel("text.", JLabel.CENTER)); 
      pane.addTab("text", new JLabel("text.", JLabel.CENTER)); 
      pane.addTab("text", new JLabel("text.", JLabel.CENTER)); 
      return pane; 
   } 
   public void init() { 
      contentPane = this.getContentPane(); 
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(30, 30)); 
      setTitle("text"); 
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
      JTabbedPane jtabbedpane = createTabbedPane(); 
      contentPane.add(new Top(), BorderLayout.NORTH);             
      contentPane.add(jtabbedpane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
      setLocationByPlatform(true); 
      setSize(1600, 1000); // 사이즈 설정 // 가로 세로 
      setVisible(true);    // 표시 
   } 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      new DBProjectPractice(); 
   } 
}
```

**Top.java**

```
import java.awt.Font; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
class Top extends JPanel{ 
   @Override 
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      super.paintComponent(g); 
      Date date = new Date(); 
      SimpleDateFormat text = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");      
      Font f = new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 15); 
      g.setFont(f);           
      g.drawString("text : " , 100, 25); 
      g.drawString("text : " + text.format(date), 1200, 25); 
      this.setSize(1600, 30); 
   } 
}
```

**Admission.java**

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Container; 
import java.awt.Font; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JComboBox; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; 
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder; 
public class Admission extends JPanel { 
   private Container pane; 
   public Admission() { 
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
      setLayout(null); 
      Admission_Button(); 
      FixLable_JLabel(); 
      ComboBox(); 
   } 
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      super.paintComponent(g); 
      Font f = new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 15); // 글꼴 설정 
      g.setFont(f); // 글꼴 지정 
      g.drawString(":::: text ::::", 100, 100); 
      g.drawString(":::: text ::::", 100, 500); 
      this.setSize(1600, 30); 
   } 
   private void Admission_Button() {  // 입사 탭의 레이아웃의 버튼 
      JButton[] Button = new JButton[3]; 
      Button[0] = new JButton(" text "); 
      Button[1] = new JButton(" text "); 
      Button[2] = new JButton(" text "); 
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
         Button[i].setSize(100,40); 
         Button[i].setLocation(1065 + i * 120, 130); 
         add(Button[i]); 
      } 
   } 
   private void FixLable_JLabel() { 
      JLabel[] FixLabel = new JLabel[15]; // 고정된 label; 
      String[] FixLabelName = { "text", "text", "text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text", 
      "text","text","text","text","text"}; 
      EtchedBorder eb = new EtchedBorder(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY); // 테두리를 넣는다.  
      int FixLableIndex = 0; 
      for (String name : FixLabelName) { 
         FixLabel[FixLableIndex] = new JLabel(name); 
         FixLabel[FixLableIndex].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);  // 가운대 정렬  
         FixLabel[FixLableIndex].setBorder(eb);                                  // 테두리 추가  
         FixLabel[FixLableIndex++].setSize(120, 30); 
      } 
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++) { 
         FixLabel[i].setLocation(100,200 + i * 30); 
      } 
      int t = 0; 
      for(int i = 7 ; i < 10 ; i++) { 
         FixLabel[i].setLocation(550,230 + t++ * 30); 
      } 
      FixLabel[10].setLocation(550, 350); 
      t = 0; 
      for(int i = 11 ; i < 14 ; i++) { 
         FixLabel[i].setLocation(1050,230 + t++ * 30); 
      } 
      FixLabel[14].setLocation(1050, 350); 
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 15; i++) { 
         add(FixLabel[i]); 
      } 
   } 
   private void ComboBox() { 
      String[] type = {"text", "text","text","text"}; 
      JComboBox<String> typeCombo = new JComboBox<String>(); 
      int num = type.length; 
      for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++) { 
         typeCombo.addItem(type[i]); 
      } 
      typeCombo.setBounds(220, 200, 1200, 30); 
      typeCombo.setSelectedItem(2); 
      add(typeCombo); 
      setVisible(true); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Solution: Don't use null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: But this is not why your GUI is freezing and not responding. Please see the answer below for the explanation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem (to me) seems to be that you're calling `setSize(...)` on your component within its own `paintComponent` method, a painting method:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Font f = new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 15);
    g.setFont(f);
    g.drawString(":::: text ::::", 100, 100);
    g.drawString(":::: text ::::", 100, 500);
    this.setSize(1600, 30);  // **** HERE ****
}
```

This is not correct and in fact dangerous, because it may try to change the component's size on any repaint, which then *calls* repaint almost recursively. Also the size that you're setting it to is unreasonable as a height of 30 can't possibly display the GUI that this JPanel holds. Don't do this.

Better:

- to set size once via `setSize(...)` within the components constructor.
- Better still to instead set preferred size by calling `setPreferredSize(Dimension d)` within the constructor.
- Even better still is to instead override the component class's `getPreferredSize()`.

---

Your other problem is that you're using null layouts. Again, while null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I will study hard about JAVA GUI. I will implement it without using null layout.